# Need help in creating my login box Responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Hi i am new to programming so i am really sorry if my issue was easy to solve

I have a website with a login for but i am unable to make that form responsive every time i try doing that the whole thing get ruined

May somebody help me please
Here is my code:

Login.Php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Login</title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/cdn-cgi/apps/head/7MFhwiAWv7ZVSNw1QEVHMkUawb0.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Login.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/General.css">
</head>
 <body>
<!-- Messenger Chat Plugin Code -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v10.0'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
  </script>

  <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"
    attribution="setup_tool"
    page_id="104580131776579">
  </div>
  
<a class="btn btn-danger" href="index.html">Cancel</a>

<div>
    <h1 style="font-size: 20px">Please Login after you Register if you don't have an account.</h1>
    <div>
    <div class="form-box">
        <div class="button-box">
            <div id="btn"></div>
                <button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onclick="Login()">
                    Login
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="toggle-btn" onclick="Register()">
                    Register
                </button>
        </div>

            <form action="validation.php" method="POST" id="Login" class="input-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Login</button>
            </form>

            <form action="registeration.php" method="POST" id="Register" class="input-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" class="input-field" placeholder="Email" required>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="input-field" placeholder="Username" required>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Password" required>
                <button type="submit" class="submit-btn">Register</button>
            </form>

    </div>
</div>
</div>


<script>
    var X = document.getElementById("Login"); 
    var Y = document.getElementById("Register"); 
    var Z = document.getElementById("btn"); 

    function Register() {
        X.style.left = "-400px";
        Y.style.left = "50px";
        Z.style.left = "110px";      
    }
    function Login() {
        X.style.left = "50px";
        Y.style.left = "450px";
        Z.style.left = "0";      
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Login.css

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: sans-serif;
color: white;
}
body{
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5),rgba(0, 0, 50, 0.5));
background-image: url(../Images/Login-Background.png);
}
.hero{
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
.form-box{
width: 380px;
height: 480px;
position: relative;
margin:auto;
background: #191919;
padding: 5px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.button-box{
width: 224px;
margin: 35px auto;
position: relative;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px 9px #ff61241f;
border-radius: 30px;
}
.toggle-btn{
padding: 10px 30px;
cursor: pointer;
background: transparent;
border: 0;
outline: none;
position: relative;
}
#btn{
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 110px;
height: 100%;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff105f,#ffad06);
border-radius: 30px;
transition: .5s;


}
.input-group{
top: 180px;
position: absolute;
width: 280px;
transition: .5s;
}
.input-field{
width: 100%;
padding: 10px 0;
margin: 5px 0;
border-left: 0;
border-top: 0;
border-right: 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
outline: none;
background: transparent;
}
.submit-btn{
width: 85%;
padding: 10px 30px;
cursor: pointer;
display: block;
margin: auto;
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff105f,#ffad06);
border: 0;
outline: none;
border-radius: 30px;
}
#Login{
left: 50px;
}
#Register{
left: 450px;
}
h1{
color: #fff !important;
margin-top: 50px !important;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
h3{
color: #fff;
text-align: center;
}
button:focus{
outline: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
```

General.css

```
html,body{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed; 
background-size: cover;
top:0px;
left:0px;
height: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
}
```

I am really sorry but i couldn't do that please help me

I am totally new to programming

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

I successfully found the answer :

```
@media (max-width: 700px){
    .form-box{
        zoom: 80%;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use CSS media queries, Also I recommend you don't declare height.

```
.form-box{
    width: 300px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .form-box{
        width: 500px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px){
    .form-box{
        width: 700px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px){
    .form-box{
        width: 800px;
    }
}
```

Comment: But the input and the buttons won't appear fully and i would like to make it responsive for any device because the media will set a static width not something like 30% of screen width